# jQuery Chosen selects disappear when form has errors (with AJAX)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-chosen

I have this problem:
[image]

As you can see there is no select, but it should be there:
[image]
Also I'm using AJAX in this form.

Maybe I should do something with jQuery, something like:

```
  $("#tool-form").bind("ajax:error", function() {
  //do something here
});
```

**Why this is happening and how I can solve this ?**

```
  <%= form_for(@website, :remote => true) do |f| %>
       <% if @website.errors.any? %>
         The form contains <%= pluralize(@website.errors.count, "error") %>
         <% @website.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      * <%= msg %>
    <% end %>
    ...
       <%= f.select :language, options_for_select(%w[English Chinese Ukrainian])%>
 <%end%>
```

Code for calling Chosen:

```
     $("#website_language").chosen();
```

Comment: How do you expect us to solve your problem when you present us with _nothing_ to work with?

Comment: Excuse me, I thaught this is some kind of common problem. Is it enough to give you code of generating this form ?